# Cannot establish connection using port number explicitly

Tags: node.js, c, heroku, server, backend

I am new to servers and networking so pardon my ignorance.

I have a Heroku application running a NodeJS server. I am using `console.log()` to output the port its using to the console. But when i use the port to try to perform a GET request from my browser it keep loading forever. My request is something this:

`https://example.herokuapp.com:28222/getHighest`

When i remove the port number, it works perfectly:

`https://example.herokuapp.com/getHighest`

I am ultimately trying to perform GET and POST request from a C application. The HTTP library i am using seemingly requires a port for a connection. I am using this library: [GitHub](https://github.com/pradyuman/socket-c/blob/master/httpclient.c). It works perfectly when i run it locally with `localhost:8080/getHighest` but not when i use my heroku app.

Comment: You only include a port number for non-standard ports. For HTTPS the default is 443. Why use 28222? What port is your Node.js app listening on, and more importantly, is Heroku wrapping that in HTTPS?

Comment: @tadman my Node app listens on the port set by Heroku in its env variables, i console log that PORT environment variable and get 28222, and yes it seems like it is wrapping everything in https

Comment: That port is probably only relevant inside that runtime container. Outside you'd just use regular HTTPS ports.

Comment: @tadman i tried it with 443 and it seems to connecting fine now. But I am getting a “ERROR reading response from socket” error when I try to do a GET request. Edit: the read() function returns no bytes

Comment: Try with `curl` first. Then try with C. Don't forget `curl` can emit C code for `libcurl`. I'm not sure if that library you linked to can even deal with HTTPS. It could be HTTP only.

Comment: @tadman works perfect with curl, If you know your way around c networking can you please look through the library I provided to see what’s going wrong? But ether way thank you so much!

Comment: `curl https://example.herokuapp.com/getHighest --libcurl getHighest.c` for example.

Comment: I don't know that library and based on a superficial look at it, I wouldn't trust it. It's way too elementary and seems HTTP only, if only *barely* that. I'd strongly recommend using `libcurl`.

Comment: @tadman interesting, the command you provided gave me a file with the necessary code to get my response. Would this method work for a POST request as well? Also, is libcurl installed on all Linux (Ubuntu)/Mac machines by default?

Comment: The nice thing about `curl` is you can set all kinds of options, including `-X POST`, and can include form arguments as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @tadman using the default https port `443` solved the issue.